# Is it possible to display tag cloud widget by category?

Tags: widgets, tags

Is it possible that Tag Cloud Widget will show only tags by category?

If a single post is from `sports` category, then the Tag Cloud Widget will only show tags about sports.

Comment: Anybody know a solution? Is possible this feature?

Answer (score 0):

this is posible to do with custom coding or with using the plugin like this:
[WP Category Tag Cloud](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-category-tag-could/)

Comment: Yes, I know these plugin, but in this case, I have to do different sidebars each category. I need a code that detect the category automatically. :(

Comment: ok, sorry, then you have to create custom widget and integrate custom functionality

Comment: Yes! But I don´t know how to custom my widget. :P

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `<?php wp_tag_cloud(array('smallest'=>10,'largest'=>22,'number'=>0,'taxonomy'=>array('category'))); ?>`